# jquery getting sequence number from selected checkbox on checkboxlist

Tags: jquery, .net

here is my code :

```
$('#CheckBoxList1').change(function () {
                var CHK = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID%>");
                var checkbox = CHK.getElementsByTagName("input");
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    for (var i = 1; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
                        if (checkbox[i].checked) {
                            markers[i - 1].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
                        }
                        else {
                            markers[i - 1].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png');
                        }

                    }
                }
          });

        });
```

in for loop I'm finding checked checkboxes from checkboxlist1.I'm setting marker colors which names are checked in chekboxlist.İt's working succesfull with for loop. But I will making this process when I checked a checkbox.I don't will using a for loop to finding all checked checkboxes.So I will do, when I checked a checkbox on chekboxlist I will getting thet checkbox's Index(sequence number) number.When I get that index number I musn't using a for loop and I can working on markers with  that index number.  İ.E 
I have a checkbox list i.e it haves 5 checkboxes tahats texes are a,b,c,d,e . For example: when I cheked 'e' checkbox I will getting that checkbox index number which is 5,when I cheked 'c' checkbox I will getting that checkbox index number which is 3

Comment: can you explain what is the sequence number and in what you are using it??

Comment: I have a checkbox list i.e it haves 5 checkboxes tahats texes are a,b,c,d,e . For example: when I cheked 'e' checkbox I will getting that checkbox index number which is 5,when I cheked 'c' checkbox I will getting that checkbox index number which is 3,

Comment: it may helps to show some html as well

Comment: thanks for whaka and ebram thatwat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the index() function. And please be aware that some IE browsers may not recognize the .change() event, rather use .propertychange as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie)

Also, what's the point of using jQuery when you still select your elements using document.getElementById?

```
$(function() {
    $('#CheckBoxList1 input').change(function() {
        var index = $('#CheckBoxList1 input').index(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: well, $(function() {...}); is a short form for $(document).ready(function() {...});. where you use the function itself depends on when you need it

Comment: I writed under the var index=...       line a alert(); if I checked 1 box it displays once,if I chacked 2 box it displays twice,when 3 display 3...  there is not a loop. why it displays so

Comment: dude I have no idea what you mean. Please set up your markup at jsfiddle.com and demonstrate what you mean